# How to run commands from VS Code terminal?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm not able to execute commands from VS Code terminal(Ctrl + `). Once i enter the command it shows **Unknown file** window as shown below:

[image]

How can i execute commands via VS Code terminal?

Comment: can you add the command ?

Comment: hello and good day dear Rocky - good day dear Nadim - many thanks for rising this topic. This is very very interesting. Rocky can you tell us some more things.. We look forward to hear from you again

Comment: This is not specific to any command instead any command if i type in terminal it shows above dialogue. For instance: **ng-v**

Comment: the same command works in command prompt and git bash but not in VSCode terminal